# "Jupyterlab Code Formatter"使い方

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

"ANACONDA.NAVIGATOR"から"JupyterLab 3.0.14"を起動して、"Jupyterlab Code Formatter"を使いたく、
下記の手順で環境構築をしました。
が、決定的な自身のスキル不足により分からないことが多だあります。

△分からない事
１，以下の「インストール手順」は、正しいのか？
２，コマンドの呼び出し方。
３，”よくある質問”の意味。
４，ツールバー、右端のアイコンの意味（画像添付、アイコンにカーソルを置くと”Format notebook”表示）

ご教授お願いします。

△インストール手順

Jupyterlab Code Formatterのドキュメントへようこそ！参照。

"前提条件
このプラグインには、Python3.6以降の環境にJupyterLabがインストールされている必要があります。"
～クリア。

インストールステップ1（プラグイン自体のインストール）

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab_code_formatter
```

～クリア

まだJupyterLab <3.0.0を使用しているユーザーの場合は、以下も実行する必要があります。

```
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab_code_formatter       
jupyter labextension install @ryantam626/jupyterlab_code_formatter
```

～クリア

インストールステップ2（サポートされているコードフォーマッターのインストール）

```
conda install black isort
```

～クリア

Rコードフォーマッター

～パス。

インストールステップ3（Jupyterlabの再起動）

～クリア

インストールステップ4（プラグインの構成）

デフォルトのフォーマッタの変更で、説明文に基づき

```
{       
    "preferences": {        
        "default_formatter": {      
            "python": "autopep8",       
            "R": "styler"       
        }       
    }       
}
```

～保存しました。

続いて、”デフォルトのフォーマッタを次々に連鎖させる”で、
”コマンドjupyterlab_code_formatter:formatとを呼び出して”と、ありますがその”コマンド”の
呼び出し方が分かりません。
で、"よくある質問"を参照。
”フォーマッターが作業できる適切なノートブック/スクリプトが開いていることを確認してください。”と、ありますが…開いていると思います。（少し自信なし）
又、（Ⅱ）では、

```
(base) PS C:\Users\genki> jupyter labextension list     
JupyterLab v3.0.16      
C:\Users\genki\anaconda3\share\jupyter\labextensions        
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab_widgets)      
        @ryantam626/jupyterlab_code_formatter v1.4.10 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab-code-formatter)        
        
Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)     
   app dir: C:\Users\genki\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter\lab
```

～恥ずかしながら、意味不明です。

以上、ご教授お願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 該当ページの`Simple Usage`の3つの例に書いてあるのでは？ [How To Use This Plugin](https://jupyterlab-code-formatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-use.html) あとインストールしたのが`black`と`isort`なら、[Keyboard Shortcuts](https://jupyterlab-code-formatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-use.html#keyboard-shortcuts), [Chaining Default Formatters One After The Other](https://jupyterlab-code-formatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-use.html#chaining-default-formatters-one-after-the-other)の変更も適用する必要があるのでは？

Comment: 他に日本語記事で環境や条件が違うようですが、参考になるかも。[Jupyter Labの拡張機能（Extension）の導入](https://inabower.hateblo.jp/entry/2019/01/07/215923), [Python - JupyterLab でコードの自動整形を行う方法について](https://pynote.hatenablog.com/entry/jupyterlab-code-formatter), [JupyterLabでコード整形（フォーマッタはautopep8）を導入](https://kazmus.hatenablog.jp/entry/2020/12/20/201728), [3.コード自動整形](https://qiita.com/canonrock16/items/d166c93087a4aafd2db4#3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E6%95%B4%E5%BD%A2)

Comment: ご助言、ありがとうございます。

Comment: "インストールステップ4（プラグインの構成）"の
"「デフォルトフォーマッターの変更」"から、
”デフォルトのフォーマッタの変更”は、見よう見まねで何とかクリアしましたが、
次の”デフォルトのフォーマッタを次々に連鎖させる”で、
”コマンドjupyterlab_code_formatter:formatとを呼び出して”とあるのですが、
その”呼び出し”方が分かりません。
従って、表示されているコードをどこに、どうコピーペーストしたらいいのか分かりません。

Comment: その上に書いてある項目名と同じなので、デフォルトを`"autopep8"`にするか`["isort", "black"]`にするかの違いでしょう。どちらを選択するか、ということですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今の自分のレベルではご助言自体を理解出来ないので、一旦、削除して再度、整理をして投稿させていただきます。